# Mount dropbox as network drive in Linux

Tags: linux, dropbox

I am selectively syncing my dropbox folder now to accomodate a limited capacity on my SSD. Is it possible instead to mount my dropbox as a network drive and NOT sync anything whatsoever, yet still allowing me easy access to ALL the files in the dropbox-cloud?

Answer (score 2):

[Fuse Filesystem 4 Dropbox](https://github.com/realriot/ff4d) might be just the thing that you are looking for. Note though that I have never used this product and do not know of the reliability of it.

Answer (score 1):

This is an upcoming feature (currently vaporware) from Dropbox. The feature has publicly been dubbed "Project Infinite". I am not sure how it will work in Macintosh or Linux. For Windows, remote files will have a cloud icon overlay on the file and not take up any space on the local drive.

Below is a screenshot of Project Infinite context menu option. I presume anything not already synced locally can be made local on a specific file basis.

[image]